# Find a rational number that agrees with this in its first four decimals

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I'm studying power series now and I'm asked to find a rational number that agrees with:

$$\int_0^{1/2} \sqrt[3]{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: Are you asked to ask others, or are you asked to sit down and look for an ansatz in what you have learned so far? We are here to help when your thoughts led you to a dead end, not to do your homework from the onset. So please, do not just post a homework problem, but also explain your attempts to solve it.

Comment: These are really not homework problems. These are just exercises that I am asked to do before we cover it in class and I am just getting ahead.

Comment: It seems that the simplest fraction with the desired property is $\frac{48}{85}$.

Comment: @user315479 Sorry but the difference escapes me.

Comment: I am not being graded on this. My understanding of the policy is that we don't want to help anyone cheat, and that's not what I am doing.

Comment: (That's what happens if I try do make a smart comment) - The simplest fraction is in fact $\frac{58}{113}$ :)

Answer (score 3):

$(1+x^2)^{1/3}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/3}{n}x^{2n}
$.

Integrate enough terms,
since each term is rational.

More details:

Note that
$\binom{1/3}{n}
=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac13-n)}{n!}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{1/2} (1+x^2)^{1/3}
&=\int_0^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/3}{n}x^{2n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/3}{n}\int_0^{1/2}x^{2n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/3}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\big|_0^{1/2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/3}{n}\frac{1}{(2n+1)2^{2n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$.

Calculate the first few terms
until one is small enough.

Comment: I can't ask wolfram alpha because i need a proof

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: @user315479 Note that the series is alternating and and the absolute value of terms is strictly decreasing. Hence it's easy to know when to stop

Comment: @Hagen: Good point.

Answer (score 0):

One way of approximating the integral would be the midpoint rule. Using n=50, n=100, and n=200 (where n is the number of rectangles) yields 0.513254362, 0.51325526, and 0.513255484 respectively. So it would seem .5132 is accurate to the first four decimal points.